# "about me" versus "about I"

Tags: grammar, subjects, objects

Consider the following sentence:

> The details in the first section are the most important ones about me.

The sentence seems completely natural, and yet, by analysis it appears that "the most important ones about me" is a subject, not an object, by which observation, to follow the standard grammar, "me" must be changed to "I".

The result is as follows:

> The details in the first section are the most important ones about I

This sentence seems unnatural. Is it correct, according to standard grammar?

Answer (score 1):

It is the word "about" that determines whether to use "me" in this case.

This book is about me
This book is about you
This book is about her
This book is about us
This book is about you
This book is about them

similarly with "for"

This book is for me
This book is for you
This book is for her
This book is for us
This book is for you
This book is for them

Other prepositions require the use of "me", e.g.

Give it **to** me.
Stand **by** me.
Stay **with** me.

Comment: Why does the preposition change the part of speech? Also note that in cases of verbs such as *to give* and *to stand*, the part of speech following the verb is indeed an object, whereas as the copular verb *to be* functions on two subjects.

Comment: *"Why does the preposition change the part of speech"* That is an interesting linguistic question. Why does *anything* change the parts of speech. It is the case in most European languages (I don't know about other languages) that prepositions do this. I don't understand your point about verbs - that seems to be another matter entirely. We could, in theory, abolish the word "me" entirely and say "He gave I an answer"  or we could abolish "I" and say "Me Tarzan".   Maybe one day this will happen.

Comment: Note: Historically English was based on  Germanic and Latinate languages. Both of these employ ***declension*** of nouns, pronouns and adjectives. English is much more based on word order and so does not need declensions so much.  Here are two links that may be of interest [German declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension)  and  [Latin declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_declension)

Comment: The preposition doesn't change the part of speech. _Me_ and _I_ are both pronouns and _about_ doesn't change them into anything else. Don't try to use grammatical terminology if you're asking a question about grammar. You'll get it wronger.

Answer (score 1):

No, your second sentence is not correct.

You are correct that the verb *be* (here appearing as "are") does not take an object, and that "the most important ones about me" is effectively a subject. (Actually it's a [subject complement](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subject_complement.htm).)

But "about me" qualifies the head noun *most important ones* which is in the [subjective case](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjective_case.htm). In English, prepositions take the [objective case](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/objective_case.htm), and it's *about me,* not *about I*.

That is, within a noun phrase, even one which is a subject complement, it's perfectly possible to have something appear in the objective case where the grammar [of a preposition, say] requires it.

Comment: In English only pronouns have case. Common nouns and multi-word noun phrases can’t have.

Comment: Hmm.  Only pronouns are *inflected* for case, perhaps.

Comment: Case *is* a type of inflection! :-)

Answer (score 1):

While I can see the argument for "the most important ones about me" being a "subject" (if the full sentence were "The person in the first section is ___", you could make a case for either "I" or "me"), the question is what role "me" has *within* "the most important ones about me".

And within that, "me" is not a subject, but rather the [object of the preposition](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_of_a_preposition.htm).

It serves to describe the "the ones" ("the most important ones *which are about me*"), and in that sense can be thought of as the "object" where the "subject" would be "the most important ones".

Comment: Then by the same reason, "He is similar to me" would be correct over "He is similar to I"? But I believe the latter is correct?

Comment: Indeed "similar to me" is correct, and "similar to I" is not, and indeed for the same reason. You may be thinking of "than" ("taller than me" vs. "taller than I"), where there's some debate, but even there the debate is about whether "than" is in fact a preposition or a conjunction (https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/than_I_me_than_he_him.htm). Assuming it is a preposition, like "about" and "to", it should also be "taller than me", not "taller than I".

Comment: And then, we would have "You are as fast as me" over "You are as fast as I"?

Comment: Not necessarily, because as with "than", the "as" here can also be seen as a conjunction, not just a preposition. When the sentence is taken to be a shortening of "You are as fast as I am", it's correct to use "I". Basically, with "than" and "as", both "me" and "I" are acceptable, whereas "to" and "about" can only be seen as prepositions and therefore only "me" is correct.

Comment: << And then, we would have "You are as fast as me" over "You are as fast as I"? >> // The situation is different here. "He sounds like I do when I've hit my finger with a hammer" can be shortened, but **nobody** ever says "He sounds like I". "He sounds like me" is fine (if missing detail) ... the pronoun defaults to the default case, the objective. Similarly with "You are as fast as I am" → "You are as fast as me".

Comment: I believe that "He sounds like me" is not accepted in standard grammar, even while being ubiquitous in vernacular, by virtue of it being an over-generalization of the form "He speaks to me".

Comment: @epl It is absolutely fine in standard grammar.

Comment: Ok, maybe, "He sounds like me" or "He sounds as I do"?